# nginx: Configuring multiple vhost without a subdomain

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I have an nginx server. I have a public IP address but I don't have any subdomains. I would like to split my dev and test servers. So can I set up these servers ie

`http://55.22.11.127/dev` and `http://55.22.11.127/test`

I've tried this in config:

```
server_name 55.22.11.127/dev;
```

No luck...

So do I have to set up a sub domain or can I set up this using trailing url it dev and test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`server_name` must be a domain name or an IP address.

There is a kind of workaround if either `dev` or `test` is only to be accessed from your laptop.

You can add the laptop-only domain name to your laptop's `/etc/hosts` file and map it to that server name. For that matter, you can put both subdomains in there if you want.

```
55.22.11.127 test.example.com dev.example.com
```

Then in Nginx you can set `server_name` to match the values in your /etc/hosts` files, with different server blocks for the two domains.

```
server {
    server_name test.example.com;
    ...
}
server {
    server_name dev.example.com;
    ...
}
```

To support multiple hosts, your collaborators either need to also share the same `/etc/hosts` entries, or you need to use real DNS entries.

This trick is also great for testing production DNS values before they resolve on the public internet.

A final option to use one `server` block for both cases, but use two different `location` blocks to contain the configurations for each of the two cases.  For example, you can set different [root](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) directive values in two different locations.